# Accessing drool rules details in Java code

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I am novice in Drools rule engine.

I have created a single rule file i.e. **.drl** file. In that file, I have defined three rules and assigned priority to each using **salience** attribute.

Once the rules have been executed, I want to know the details of the rules that have been executed like rule name, salience value. Also, i want the order in which the rules have been executed.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AgendaEventListener for this:

```
import org.drools.event.rule.AfterActivationFiredEvent;
import org.drools.event.rule.DefaultAgendaEventListener;

...
StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
ksession.addEventListener(new DefaultAgendaEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void afterActivationFired(AfterActivationFiredEvent event) {
        AgendaItem item  = (AgendaItem) event.getActivation();
        System.out.println("Name: " + item.getRule().getName() + "; Salience: " + item.getRule().getSalience());
    }
});
```

The event will fire for every rule that gets fired.
Be careful, this might not work in future version since I assume the `Activation` is an `AgendaItem` object. I do this in order to get access to salience (need access to `Rule` the class instead of `Rule` the interface).

As an alternative where you have total control what gets logged when, you could register a tracking fact and call the tracking method manually, something like this:

```
import org.drools.rule.Rule;
public class RulesTracking {

    private List<String> tracking = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void track(Rule rule) {
        tracking.add("Name: " + rule.getName() + "; Salience: " + rule.getSalience());
    }

    public List<String> getTracking() {
        return tracking;
    }

}
```

Then in the class where you set up the session, you create and register a tracking object as a "fact" and after all the processing gets done you can output the tracking result:

```
...
rulesTracking = new RulesTracking(); // register this as a "fact"
// more stuff, fireAllRules
System.out.println(rulesTracking.getTracking());
...
```

In the end, you call the tracking method wherever you need it, here's a test rule:

```
// test rule that fires for every product
rule "TestRule"
salience 100
when
    $product : Product()
    $rulesTracking : RulesTracking()
then
    $rulesTracking.track(drools.getRule()); // here you call your tracking method manually, absolute control
end
```